# LNK2001 error in Visual Studio 2015 when using glew

Tags: c++, glew

I recently tried to  start using OpenGL, and since I'm a Windows user, I had to install glew. Now I have a basic program with my glew.h header linked in the main cpp file; my glew32.lib file is linked to the project and the dll file is in the Debug folder. Everything should work, except it doesn't! I still get LNK2001 errors :

```
1>Source.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu ___glewDisableVertexAttribArray
1>Source.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu ___glewEnableVertexAttribArray
1>Source.obj : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu ___glewVertexAttribPointer
```

(from the VS output window)

Do you know how I should go about solving this issue? Other people have suggested I change Linker settings, link .lib files, check .h location etc. but I've done all of that without success (or rather without enough success, it still removed many error codes but not all of them).

Thanks in advance, feel free to ask for additional info if you want to :)

Comment: Is there an error saying can not open `glew32.lib`?

Comment: No, those are the only error messages I get (not counting the global one : `C:\Users\...myfile.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 3 externes non résolus`)